# Integrating Quickbooks online without quickbooks widgets

Tags: quickbooks

I want to Integrate My .Net Web Application to Quickbooks Online. I can do this by using the QuickBook Widgets(Connect to QuickBook button). This will load popup window for authorization. But I want to do this without popup windows and only through a direct service call.

Is there a way to do this by using a direct service call and without loading intuit Authentication and Authorization popup windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *very first time the user connects* you **MUST** authenticate to IPP/Intuit Data Services via the pop-up/widgets.

Once you do that, you'll have a long-lived (6+ months, with an option to renew them) set of OAuth tokens which you can store and use from that point forward. Once you have those tokens, you no longer need to show the "Connect to QuickBooks" button (and thus the pop-up window).

You *do* still need to show the other widgets (the blue dot menu).